# How do subpixel operations work?

Tags: opencv

What is the theory (simplified) behind subpixel operations used in computer vision programs? I'm using OpenCV to detect points on a pattern and there is a method used to refine the detection to subpixel accuracy. How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

When you consider light projecting onto a camera sensor from a scene there will be aliasing effects from the discrete elements in the camera sensor. Say you have a series of adjacent pixels which have values

| 10 | 15 | 17 | 22 | 68 | 95 | 121 |

and you wanted to obtain a more accurate estimate of the intensity at a 3D point which projected to a 2D point between the 4th and 5th pixel it would be a fairly poor approximation to just assume the intensity of the light reflecting off this point would be 22 or 68 (say by picking the nearest neighbor), a better approximation would be to assume some kind of smooth transition between these value is occuring on the surface and try to estimate from there. A simple guess is to go with a [linear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) as this is computationally quite cheap however more sophisticated examples can be found.